# Boostrap datepicker shows calendar on page load in IE

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker on my form. When the pages loads in Chrome I see the textbox for the date and the datepicker button which when clicked will show the calendar. Unfortunately in IE the calendar shows when the page loads which looks pretty ugly.

Before making this post I looked around on Google and post on here but didn't come across anything that works in js.

Any suggestions of how to make IE not show the calendar until the date picker button is pressed?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to initialize datepicker with hide

```
$("#inputId").datepicker('hide');
```

Comment: The issue turned out to be this js /$("#TimeCardDate").focus(); which is the same as clicking the textbox to see the calendar. Removing that with pc_coder's snippet seems to work.